# Where can I follow, occasionally, the overall state of the "TeX ecosphere"?

Tags: latex-project

I was recently surprised by a comment on a question, telling me that what I had thought was where the multilingual mainstream was "going" - namely xelatex and polyglossia - was actually not as favored, with lualatex and babel recommended. 5 or 6 years ago, it was the opposite: babel was considered more clunky and less system-font-friendly (for RTL languages at least), and it was hinted one might want to move away from pdfetex + babel.

This led me to the realization that I'm not really exposed to TeX-related news - even as a (less active) user on this site. I was wondering where I could read up on the "state of the TeX world" these days, but a bit of web searching led me to places like this:

https://www.rubbernews.com/events/2021-international-latex-conference

or even less relevant :-)

Now, I now there are some TeX-related journals, but I'm not interested in following closely or the deep technical details. This question is about the state and prognosis of major projects, central people/bodies involved etc.

Comment: this site is as good as any (that's mostly why I hang around here, to keep an eye on how things are really used, and whether things we put in to latex work in practice)

Comment: I'm not persuaded that babel should be preferred over polyglossia. Yes, the former is the officially supported package, but it's also weighed down by backwards compatibility for 8-bit encodings (and backwards compatibility is a major concern for the TeX core people).

Comment: Both babel and polyglossia work with xelatex and lualatex, and now that HarfBuzz font renderer is in both engines, there is not much difference font-wise between the two. Perhaps the question might resolve into: What news for those stuck with (constrained to) legacy fonts and 8-bit world? And those not?

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** an answer to your main question, but since you start with the current status of `babel`, I think some clarifications in this regard would be helpful.

In the `babel` [site](https://latex3.github.io/babel/) you can find the latest news with the most recent features, which are mainly for luatex because many of them are not possible with xetex. Here is a selection:

- Support total or partial for about 250 languages, with basic templates for 500 more and a way to define easily new ones from scratch.
- Non-standard hyphenation, including repeated hyphens, weighted rules...
- Automatic directionality, with no explicit markup.
- Arabic justification (still tentative, but it will be useable in the next release).
- Counters for many languages.

See also the samples here:

https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/main/samples

Comment: I didn't ask about news regarding a single package, but rather something that's more macro-level; a bird's eye view.

Comment: I've edited the beginning to clarify the rationale for my answer.

Comment: ... I only use babel vs polyglossia as an anecdote, so this would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact foci of the question, but browsing the contents of the [compiled Latex Project News document](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews.pdf), and the introduction paragraphs for some of the items, can give you some idea of where certain things are going.